# AttributeError using pympler / muppy

Tags: python, memory-profiling

Pympler is not working when I include my library.

```
from pympler import tracker
import my_library

tr = tracker.SummaryTracker()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    tr = tracker.SummaryTracker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pympler/tracker.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.s0 = summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pympler/muppy.py", line 45, in get_objects
    if not _is_containerobject(ref):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pympler/muppy.py", line 246, in _is_containerobject
    if type(o).__flags__ & __TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC == 0:
AttributeError: __flags__
```

If I remove the import of my_library, it works fine. Any ideas where I should start looking?

Alternatively, what should I use as a replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed [here](https://github.com/pympler/pympler/issues/24).

It turned out to be that some [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/) objects not having a `__flags__` attribute. Now muppy supports such types.